# How to make a Mysql insert statement conditionally occur depending on the result of a 1 Select Statement

Tags: java, mysql, triggers

Consider what my Ajax call looks like (below the code I explain the issue):

```
 $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "servlet",
                data: {course_name_param:selectedOption},
                dataType:"json",
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#startDate').empty();
              $('#startDate').append('<option value="">Select Start Date</option>');
     $.each(data, function(index, jsonData) {

  /*Here below is where I check availability*/
 if(jsonData.students_registered < jsonData.max_size){

      /*Display available courses*/
  }
}
```

I have a MySQL table that holds information on courses available for educational sessions. 1 of these fields is available slots(maximum capacity).

Registration is an insert statement. I need to control this by checking the slots actually available when inserting.

Currently, I perform the check with Ajax calls to this table. The check is useless when multiple users load the page relatively close in timing(less than a minute).

**Question:**

- How can I accomplish this away from the front-end?
- Is this something that should be included into the class that holds the logic for my 
  Insert statements?

  I don't see this scenario being considered in SO questions, only in the case of avoiding duplicate entries, this is not my case.

  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you looping through?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk Looping through the rows of course information returned from ajax call.

Comment: I'm thinking you could simply implement the condition into your SQL query, though I'd need an idea of your database schema to be of further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "before insert" trigger on the table where the user inserts. I went with this approach. Then handling the SQLException in the application:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER before_insert_registration
BEFORE INSERT ON registration 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE num_rows INTEGER;

Declare x INTEGER;
SET x = NEW.course_id;

SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
INTO num_rows FROM  courses
WHERE
    course_id = NEW.course_id
        AND maxsize > students_registered;

    IF num_rows < 1 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Testing Custom Fail-Over';
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply structure your query in such a way that you only pull back the courses with open slots. Something like this might give you an idea:

```
SELECT   courses.title
FROM     courses 
WHERE    students_registered < max_size
```

If you want to ensure validation on the database, you can use a conditional insert:

```
INSERT INTO enrollments(course_id, student_id)  
SELECT <your course id>, <your student id> FROM dual
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM courses
  WHERE  id = <your course id>
  AND    students_registered < max_size
)
```

Comment: Can this check  be done at the moment the user attempts to insert?

Comment: Absolutely, that makes it much simpler. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I'll update you when I have a chance to test this, right now we're live so I don't have the window for changes.

Comment: Drazen,  the select returns 20+ rows. See the select I'm using: SELECT 2 FROM dual WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_id = 2 AND students_registered < maxsize )

Comment: I can't imagine how that could ever return more than one row.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I'm using your query as is. No mods.

Comment: Could be that `dual` behaves differently in MySQL than in Oracle. Try: SELECT val FROM (SELECT 2 as val)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM courses
  WHERE  id = 2
  AND    students_registered < max_size
)

Comment: Or simply: SELECT 2 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id = 2 AND students_registered < max_size )

Comment: Shouldn't be an opening bracket in front of WHERE. Sure you got it right?

Comment: I have the select that works, but the insert happens even when the select returns nothing. Here is the select:

SELECT course_id from courses 
WHERE
course_id = (
  SELECT course_id FROM courses
  WHERE  course_id = 3
  AND maxsize > students_registered);

Comment: How do I make the insert fail when the select returns nothing or null? Or where can I look for this? im out of ideas.

Comment: You've given me insight on the direction I could go.

Comment: The WHERE EXISTS clause should nullify the insert if it returns nothing (i.e. students registered = max size).

Comment: When you say "nullify", are you assuming I want to insert the values that are coming from the db? Or, the fact that the select returns nothing, this should stop the insert from executing? I expected the behavior of the latter, this would be ideal.

Comment: The select returning nothing in the where exists clause should prevent any insert from occurring, yes. The value inserted would be '2' from 'SELECT 2' in my last example.

Comment: But that's not what I want to insert, I have a form that submits the info I need. The select just lets me know if there's a slot available. So my best bet would be a before trigger or a stored proc you think?

Comment: There are two select statements, the first one is basically a pseudo/dummy select for the values you intend on inserting. The second one, in the where exists clause, is for checking whether that course is full or not. If it returns a row, meaning it's not full (students_registered < max_size), it proceeds with the insert, and if it doesn't, meaning it is, your insert fails.